# Commit an temporary table while fetching rows T-SQL (SqlServer2005)

Tags: sql-server

I Update a temporary table during a "While.. fetch next"
The problem is that, when the cursor fetch the next row th e temporary table is not update with the fetch next before so at the end of the while the temporary table it's update with the data of last row instead of data of each row.
Ps : i don't speak very well english, i hope you can understand my request

```
        DECLARE @IdType UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @SerialNumber NVARCHAR(64)
DECLARE DeviceCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        --Acc.[AccountHierarchyId],
        MC.SerialNumber  AS SerialNumber,
        MC.IdType AS IdType
    FROM 
        @MachinesContrat MC
    WHERE
        MC.TypeAffaire = 'Essentiel'

OPEN DeviceCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM DeviceCursor INTO @SerialNumber, @IdType
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

        UPDATE 
            MI SET MI.SerialNumber = @SerialNumber
        FROM 
            @MachinesInventory MI
        WHERE
            MI.fk_IdType = @IdType AND isnull(MI.SerialNumber,'Dummy') <> @SerialNumber

    FETCH NEXT FROM DeviceCursor    INTO @SerialNumber, @IdType
END
CLOSE DeviceCursor;  
DEALLOCATE DeviceCursor;
```

Comment: Is it possible to add sample data that shows the contents of your table before and after the update.  Can you also add what you want the table to contain post update?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a cursor to do the job. A simple join in your update statement can do it and will be more performant.